# Access SQL - divide value in each row by total (using self join)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table (tblGoals) which shows how many goals each player has scored, e.g:

```
| Player  | Goals  |
--------------------
|  John   |   6    |
|  Chris  |   10   |
|  Ben    |   4    |
```

I am trying to write a query that will output each player along with the percentage of the teams total goals that they have scored:

```
| Player  | PercentageGoals  |
------------------------------
|  John   |       0.3        |
|  Chris  |       0.5        |
|  Ben    |       0.2        |
```

I have already figured out how to do this with a sub query as shown

```
SELECT 
    Player, 
    Goals/ (SELECT SUM(Goals)FROM tblGoals) AS PercentageGoals
FROM tblGoals
```

The example table I have shown is just to demonstrate what I am trying to do. The actual table I am using is a much larger dataset and trying to use a subquery to get the percentage in this way is running quite slowly.

I have noticed before in Access that self-joins are usually optimised more efficiently than sub queries, and so I am trying to figure out if the above query can be rewritten using a self join.

I have tried something along the lines of below but obviously this is incorrect as t2 is grouped by Player which means I am not getting the true total, but if I leave the Player name out then I can't join on it?

```
SELECT 
    t1.Player, 
    t1.Goals/t2.sumGoals AS PercentageGoals
FROM 
    tbl1 t1 
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT Player, SUM(Goals) as sumGoals 
     FROM tbl1 
     GROUP BY Player) t2 
ON t1.Player= t2.Player
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Thank you for saving me from one-and-a-half days worth of frustration. Your example for dividing within a sub-query was a big help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try this as an answer - although I'm not sure if it will be faster as only using a three records.

Your second table in the join should just have a total of all the goals to join to each record in the first table - a cartesian product.

You can then divide one by the other:

```
SELECT    Player
        , Goals / TotalGoals AS Total
FROM    tblGoals, (SELECT SUM(Goals) AS TotalGoals FROM tblGoals)
```

Is it any faster on a big table?  The idea being that in your SQL it was calculating the total for each record, while this creates the total as a table and joins to it so should only be calculated once.

Comment: As far as I know, Access is smart enough to cache the result of subqueries if there are no records from the outer query used in the subquery. I doubt that there's any speed difference, even in large data sets. It's more correct to not rely on this caching, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Darren. I've left the office now but will test this tomorrow morning and let you know if it's any quicker. Cheers

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth  Not sure.  On a larger table of 550891 records the original query took 655ms, while my version took 374ms (which means nothing, as second time I ran it it took 640ms... everyone in the office is logging off at the moment though). My speed test code: `Private Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long:Sub Test():Dim s As Long:s = GetTickCount:DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query2", acViewNormal:Debug.Print GetTickCount - s:End Sub`

Comment: I have tested on my datatset this morning and it appears to be running about 30% quicker. Thanks Darren